# UITableView cell goes blank when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have setup a single section, single cell custom cell in a UITableViewController to display a view that was longer than the screen. However when testing I notice the cell will disappear (go blank) when scrolling down before it leaves the view area. It's nothing fancy, but I don't understand why it would would disappear when scrolling down, especially when it is nowhere near leaving the viewable area.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

VendorDetailCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VendorDetailCell"];
cell.vendorImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: self.imageData.data];
cell.vendorTitle.text = self.imageData.vendorTitle;
cell.vendorDescription.text = self.imageData.vendorDescription;



   return cell;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to allocate a cell in case `tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does not return a cell by checking `if (cell == nil)` then you'd have to allocate your custom cell, I believe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when the frame of the cell in the table view is scrolled so it's outside of the frame of the table view.

- Do you implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?
- Is that height the height of cell?
- Would the cell be better served as being broken up into several cells
  in one section of the table view?