# Why does insertRowsAtIndexPaths always cause the TableView to scroll to the top?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been banging my head on this problem for hours, but every time I try something like this:

```
    self.dataArray.append(newCellObj)
```

and then I do this:

```
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

The UITableView will automatically scroll to the top of the page.

Even if I try:

```
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

The UITableView will still scroll to the top even with scrolling completely disabled. What exactly causes the ScrollView to scroll to the top after `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is called?

The only solution I have for this issue is to use this:

```
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

instead. If I use reloadData instead than it's fine, but then I lose the nice animation which I'd really like to keep.

I also have `self.tableView.scrollsToTop = false` and I've tried many other configurations like that that could disable scrolling somehow, but, there's something that overrides this after `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: I think you may have some other code reacting poorly here. You're right that it shouldn't be scrolling to the top. Have you tried doing it without being between begin/end updates? Is there any other code that *might* be relevant?

Comment: @RyanPoolos Thanks mate, it works better without the begin/end updates for me. :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was encountering the same issue as OP. Additionaly, sometimes some of my table view cells would go "blank" and disappear altogether, which led me to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199583/uitableview-cell-goes-blank-when-scrolling).

For me, the solution was to do ONE of the following:

- implement  `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`
- disable auto layout
- set a more accurate `estimatedRowHeight` on my `UITableView`

Comment: THANK YOU! `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` seems to have completely resolved the issue! It seems to serve as more of a `maximum height for row at index path`, when I set this value to something far too high than the average cell in my tableView, it seems to have done the trick. And I was also able to keep `auto layout` turned on! :D      I have several of these "update table view" functions all over my project, each deals with a completely different class of cell, and the estimatedHeight trick fixed every single one of them. The alternative to this i guess is manual heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I have the same problem but `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and `estimatedRowHeight` didn't work.

Comment: I found the root cause: `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];` is my problem. Remove this line then it worked, without need both of `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`, `estimatedRowHeight`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

// I'm use auto layout and this variant without animation works 
// ...insert object to datasource
NSUInteger idx = [datasource indexOfObject:myNewObject];
if ( NSNotFound != idx )
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
    [self.table beginUpdates];
    [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.table endUpdates];
    [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path 
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom 
                              animated:NO];
}
```